# Can/should Task<TResult> be wrapped in a C# 5.0 awaitable which is covariant in TResult?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, covariance, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm really enjoying working with C# 5.0 asynchronous programming. However, there are a few places where updating old code to be consistent with the TAP model is causing problems for me.

Here's one of them - I'm not sure exactly why [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424) is not covariant in TResult, but it's causing problems for me when trying to update a covariant interface to move from a synchronous to an asychronous pattern:

Old code:

```
public interface IInitializable<out T> // ** out generic modifier **
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Boolean to indicate if class is ready
    /// </summary>
    bool IsInitialized { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls for instance to be initialized using current parameters
    /// Driver initialization can be done in the default constructor if desired
    /// </summary>
    T Initialize();
}
```

New code (won't compile):

```
public interface IAsyncInitializable<out T> // ** out generic modifier...broken **
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Boolean to indicate if class is ready
    /// </summary>
    bool IsInitialized { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls for instance to be initialized using current parameters
    /// Driver initialization can be done in the default constructor if desired
    /// </summary>
    Task<T> InitializeAsync(); // ** breaks because Task<TResult> is invariant in TResult **
}
```

Is there is a reasonable way around this without modifying my APIs too drastically? (Bonus: why is Task not covariant?). There's no IAwaitable interface, but I suppose I could make one and create an extension method that converts to a wrapped, covariant, awiatable task object. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: BTW, even if `Task` was a covariant interface, your code wouldn't compile. The correct version would be `Task<T> InitializeAsync();` (without the `out` modifier on that line).

Comment: An excellent point. I'd corrected that in VS, but forgot to edit SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Task<T>` can't be covariant in `T`, because it's a class. Only interfaces and delegates can have generic variance.

As for whether it's worth doing the wrapping... I guess that depends on how much you use the covariance within your project. I suspect you'll find all the wrapping and unwrapping confusing over time, to be honest - if it's not *too* bad to just take the hit of removing the covariance, I'd do that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I implemented IAwaitable(out TResult) using your Eduasync TaskAwaiter(T), and can see that use of a separate interface is definitely not worth the loss of readability/usability. And, great point re: classes and generic variance...honored to have my mistake pointed out by @Jon Skeet :). No ITask(out T) is a bummer, though. I see Stephen Cleary's comment here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407227/async-generic-delegate-in-c-sharp-5-0), but WinRT interop compatibility is a little bit unsatisfying as a justification for using the concrete type.

Comment: @DavidCuccia: You should read up on Stephen Toub's blog about propagating contexts when it comes to awaiters. It gets a bit trickier than Eduasync shows :(

Comment: @JonSkeet - Any idea why they framework developers didn't add an `ITask<T>` and only implemented a class?

Comment: @PhilipPittle: For one thing, `Task<T>` came along before async/await - it was designed mostly for parallelism. There are various things that might have been different if it had been designed from scratch now.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that not including compiler support for the async keyword on an ITask interface was a major oversight on Microsoft's part.  Luckily it's not too hard to work around this limitation.

I have implemented a covariant awaitable `ITask<out TResult>` interface.  Its usage is pretty straightforward.

More information can be found at:

https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask

Comment: Very nice work indeed. The use of generalized async return types in your library was highly educational.