# Why is Task<T> not co-variant?

Tags: c#, task, covariance

```
class ResultBase {}
class Result : ResultBase {}

Task<ResultBase> GetResult() {
    return Task.FromResult(new Result());
}
```

The compiler tells me that it cannot implicitly convert `Task<Result>` to `Task<ResultBase>`. Can someone explain why this is? I would have expected co-variance to enable me to write the code in this way.

Comment: Infterfaces can only be covariant or contravariant. Class always are invariant. Read more on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107071/why-classes-that-implement-variant-interfaces-remain-invariant

Comment: Classes are invariant in C#.

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204755/can-should-tasktresult-be-wrapped-in-a-c-sharp-5-0-awaitable-which-is-covarian) it appears that someone has written [a covariant ITask<T> wrapper](https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask) for it. Also one can vote on [a suggestion to implement it here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5754247-make-task-t-implement-covariant-interface-itask-o).

Comment: In this example you can provide the type parameter explicitly: `Task.FromResult<ResultBase>(new Result())`. It will compile. But yes, `Task` is invariant, which is bad.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to [someone who may be in the know](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a350bb3-b1cc-48a1-8684-8e67cf17bf55/lack-of-covariance-in-the-task-class?forum=async)...

> The justification is that the advantage of covariance is outweighed by
>   the disadvantage of clutter (i.e. everyone would have to make a
>   decision about whether to use Task or ITask in every single
>   place in their code).

It sounds to me like there is not a very compelling motivation either way.  `ITask<out T>` would require a lot of new overloads, probably quite a bit under the hood (I cannot attest to how the actual base class is implemented or how special it is compared to a naive implementation) but way more in the form of these `linq`-like extension methods.

Somebody else made a good point - the time would be better spent making `class`es covariant and contravariant. I don't know how hard that would be, but that sounds like a better use of time to me.

On the other hand, somebody mentioned that it would be very cool to have a real `yield return` like feature available in an `async` method. I mean, without sleight of hand.

Comment: `async`, `await` relies on the existence of a suitable `GetAwaiter` method so it's already decoupled from the `Task` class.

Comment: Actually `Task`, `Task<>`, `IAsyncEnumerable<>` or `IAsyncEnumerator<>` is required to make `async` `await` code in c#. A class with the `GetAwaiter` method alone is not enough. At least, this is what the compiler says.

Comment: @FranciscoNeto That's simply not true.  `async`/`await` only rely on the existence of a `GetAwaiter` method which returns an object having `IsCompleted`, `OnCompleted` and `GetResult` members with appropriate signatures.  Custom implementations of awaitables are therefore possible.  [See here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/05/13/eduasync-part-3-the-shape-of-the-async-method-awaitable-boundary/)

Answer (score 20):

I realize I'm late to the party, but here's an extension method I've been using to account for this missing feature:

```
/// <summary>
/// Casts the result type of the input task as if it were covariant
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The original result type of the task</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TResult">The covariant type to return</typeparam>
/// <param name="task">The target task to cast</param>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static async Task<TResult> AsTask<T, TResult>(this Task<T> task) 
    where T : TResult 
    where TResult : class
{
    return await task;
}
```

This way you can just do:

```
class ResultBase {}
class Result : ResultBase {}

Task<Result> GetResultAsync() => ...; // Some async code that returns Result

Task<ResultBase> GetResultBaseAsync() 
{
    return GetResultAsync().AsTask<Result, ResultBase>();
}
```

Comment: From what namespace?

Comment: @BennyM `Task<T>` and the `ContinueWith` method are in the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace, while the `MethodImpl` attribute is in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`.

Comment: Some additional advice:
If you just want to downcast, like in the example, this works as well:
`Task.FromResult<ResultBase>(new Result());`

Comment: Actually this latter comment should be the accepted answer since the whole problem is not about covariance but a situation that is an already supported by the framework.

Comment: Do not use that. ContinueWith should not be used with Async Flow.
Especially when you do not define that you need to handle it asynchrounously.

Comment: @Shoter that is a very good point, in fact I originally wrote this answer 2 years ago when I had way less experience with the intricacies of async code in C#. I've updated my answer, the code is now equivalent and should also preserve the stack trace correctly when used. The performance should be roughly the same as well: you get an additional async state machine but you get rid of the delegate invocation that was there before. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: This code is creating additional async state machine which will have impact on performance.

This is still not ideal solution. I wonder if there is ideal one though.

Comment: @Shoter I know it adds some overhead due to the additional async state machine (which is why I had originally not done so), but it's the only proper way to do this that I'm aware of. As you pointed out, the previous approach was using `ContinueWith` which is highly discouraged with the async flow, and which also cases the stack traces to basically be lost, or at least partially lost when that method is somewhere in the execution flow. If there's a better way to do this I'd love to learn what that is! Until then, I think this is the best approach for this particular issue.

Comment: Why the explicit `where TResult : class`?

Answer (score 3):

I've had success with the [MorseCode.ITask NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MorseCode.ITask/). At this point it's pretty stable (no updates in a few years) but it was trivial to install and the only thing you needed to do to translate from an ITask to a Task was call `.AsTask()` (and the reverse extension method also ships with the package).

Answer (score -1):

In my case I didn't know Task generic argument in compile time and had to work with System.Threading.Tasks.Task base class. Here is my solution created from the example above, perhaps will help someone.

```
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static async Task<T> AsTask<T>(this Task task)
    {
        var taskType = task.GetType();
        await task;
        return (T)taskType.GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
    }
```

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile-time then you shouldn't be using generics at all. Also, this function will perform very slowly because you're using reflection - and it will fail if `Task` is not `Task<T>` at runtime.

Comment: @Dai, yep, it's just a prototype, there should be a type check