# Await the result of Task<TDerived> using reflection in a non-generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, async-await

Consider the following case:

```
class A
{
    public int Id;
}

class B : A
{

}

class Main
{
    public async Task<int> Create(Type type)
    {
        MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("Create", new Type[] { typeof(string) }).MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { type });
        A a = await (Task<A>)method.Invoke(this, new object[] { "humpf" });
        return a.Id;
    }

    public async Task<T> Create<T>(string name) where T : A
    {
        T t = await Foo.Bar<T>(name);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Calling `new Main().Create(typeof(B))` will fail with a

> Unable to cast object of type '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task[B]`' to
>   type '`System.Threading.Tasks.Task[A]`'

I don't quite understand because in this case, the Generic `Create<T>` method can only return a `Task<T>` where `T` is always derived from '`A`', but maybe I'm missing an edge case here.
Besides that, how can I make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Unlike interfaces, concrete types such as `Task<TResult>` cannot be covariant. See [Why is Task<T> not co-variant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant). So `Task<B>` cannot be assigned to a `Task<A>`.

Comment: Thanks for that link! That helps. Now how do I work around this? :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As per my comment:

> Unlike interfaces, concrete types such as `Task<TResult>` cannot be covariant. See [Why is Task not co-variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant). So `Task<B>` cannot be assigned to a `Task<A>`.

The best solution I can think of is to use the underlying type `Task` to perform the `await` like so:

```
var task = (Task)method.Invoke(this, new object[] { "humpf" });
await task;
```

Then you can use reflection to get the value of the `Result`:

```
var resultProperty = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(type).GetProperty("Result");
A a = (A)resultProperty.GetValue(task);
return a.Id;
```

Comment: Why not just `task.GetType()` instead of `typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(type)` ?

Comment: `task.GetType()` would most likely always be fine, but if the resulting `Task` was a derived type which shadowed `Result` it would throw an `AmbiguousMatchException`. Like this that can never possibly happen as I am being more explicit over where I expect to find the `Result` property.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren I have no idea but it's possible, so I think it's safer to cater for that possibility.

Comment: @Lukazoid I'm using reflection to unwrap the task result because I don't know the type. If I knew the type I would just cast the value to `Task<Whatever>`.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren How would you do that cast if you only knew the type at runtime, like in the question?

Comment: @Lukazoid if the type parameter is dynamic you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to get task result in Castle Interceptor. This code works for me:

```
if (invocation.ReturnValue is Task task)
{
    task.Wait();

    var result = invocation.ReturnValue.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
    _cacheProvider.Set(_key, result, _duration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My option has form of extension method. It takes any instance of `Task` and returns `Task<object?>` with actual result for generic tasks or `null` for non-generic ones.

```
internal static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<object> ToGenericTaskAsync(this Task task)
    {
        await task;
        var taskType = task.GetType();
        if (!IsAssignableToGenericTaskType(taskType))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return task
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty("Result", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)!
            .GetValue(task);
    }

    private static bool IsAssignableToGenericTaskType(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType &&
            type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>) &&
            type.GetGenericArguments()[0] != Type.GetType("System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult"))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return type.BaseType is not null && IsAssignableToGenericTaskType(type.BaseType);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Task<object?> t1 = await Task.CompletedTask.ToGenericTaskAsync();
Task<object?> t2 = await Task.FromResult<int>(5).ToGenericTaskAsync();
```

Example in [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KTsWxJ)

Answer (score -1):

The above solution really helped me.  I made a small tweak to the @Lukazoid solution...

```
var resultProperty = typeof(Task<>).MakeGenericType(type).GetProperty("Result");
A a = (A)resultProperty.GetValue(task);
```

to

```
dynamic a = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result")?.GetValue(task);
```