# How to get task result from awaiting a non generic task

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, task

I have the following method:

```
public async Task Execute()
{
    object previous = null;

    // _delegates is of type IReadOnlyCollection<Delegate>
    foreach (Delegate method in _delegates) 
    {
        Task executing = (Task) (previous != null
           ? method.DynamicInvoke(_repository, previous)
           : method.DynamicInvoke(_repository);

        await executing;

        // pseudo code here
        if (executing returns something)
           previous = executing.Result //<-- ?
        else
           previous = null;
    }
}
```

Basically I iterate over a list of delegates that I execute in order. Each delegate receives a repository as argument, and the return value of the previous delegate (if there was any).

Some delegates return a `Task` and some return a `Task<TResult>`. If encountered with the latter, I want to store the `TResult` value in `previous` so I can pass it as an argument to the next delegate.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Reflection to check if the type of the `executing` object is `Task<T>` and then read the "Result" property if so like this:

```
var taskType = executing.GetType();

bool isTaskOfT =
    taskType.IsGenericType
    && taskType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Task<>);

if (isTaskOfT)
{
    object result = taskType.GetProperty("Result").GetValue(executing);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to test this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Was just trying something similar myself :) Good one

Comment: Just a warning that this check can't reliably determine Task<TResult>, depending on the runtime, e.g. it can be `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+Asyn‌​cStateMachineBox1[TR‌​esult,TStateMachine]`

Answer (score -3):

In if you need to add casting:

```
if (executing returns something)
    previous = ((Task<object>)executing).Result
else
    previous = null;
```

Comment: Then Task<object> ?

Comment: @MarcinDudek That would work if [Task was co-variant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant)