# Generic policy type return

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, polly

I want to retry when the NEST error is in a range of HttpCodeResponse and I have the follow generic policy:

```
 public Policy<D> CreatePolicy<T, D>(
            PolicyType policyType)
            where T : Exception where D : IApiCallDetails
        {
            switch (policyType)
            {
                case PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync:

                    var httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying = new List<string>(this.policyConfiguration.HttpStatusCodesToRetrying.Split(','));

                    return Policy.Handle<T>()
                        .OrResult<D>(r => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Select(int.Parse).ToList().Contains(r.HttpStatusCode.Value))
                        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                            this.policyConfiguration.NumberOfRequestRetries,
                            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.policyConfiguration.TimeInSecondsBetweenRetries),
                            onRetry: (exception, retryCount, context) =>
                            {
                                Log.Error($"[{context.PolicyKey}] Retry {retryCount}  due to {exception.Exception.Message}.");
                                throw exception.Exception;
                            })                        
                        .WithPolicyKey(nameof(PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync));

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(policyType), policyType, null);
            }
```

But when I try to apply to an elasticClient call, I receive the error:

> can not implicity convert System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Nest.ISearchResponse<Model.Product>> to System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Elasticsearch.Net.IApiCallDetails>

```
 Policy<IApiCallDetails> policyWaintAndRetry = this.policyFactory.CreatePolicy<ElasticsearchClientException, IApiCallDetails>(PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync);


        var searchResponse = await policyWaintAndRetry.ExecuteAsync
            action: () =>
                this.client.SearchAsync<Product>(s => s
                .From((request.PageNumber - 1) * request.PageSize)
                .Size(request.PageSize)
                .Index(GetIndexName(request.TenantId))
                .Query(q => tq), CancellationToken.None),
            contextData: new Polly.Context("SearchProductSearchAsync"))
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show what the actual types are (twice), where the second code example currently has `var`?

Comment: Done, @mountaintraveller

Comment: What is the `var` in `var searchResponse`?

Comment: I edit again: Policy<IApiCallDetails>

Comment: This looks like a standard generic covariance and contravariance problem.  `Task<TResult>` is not covariant.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant . Read up on generic covariance and contravariance.

Answer (score 1):

For NEST 5.x, I think `D` should have a generic parameter constraint of [`IResponse`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Nest/CommonAbstractions/Response/ResponseBase.cs); every response within NEST implements `IResponse` and the [`ApiCall` property](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Responses/IBodyWithApiCallDetails.cs#L12) *inherited* from `IBodyWithApiCallDetails` contains the `IApiCallDetails` with the [HTTP status code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Responses/IApiCallDetails.cs#L38).

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to define two separate policies for handling exceptions and results.  The two separate policies in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928173/) could be combined like this:

```
public Policy<TResult> CreatePolicyForResultAndException<TResult, TException>(PolicyType policyType)
    where TResult : HttpResponseMessage
    where TException: Exception
{
    switch (policyType)
    {
        case PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync:

            var httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying = new List<string>(this.policyConfiguration.HttpStatusCodesToRetrying.Split(','));

            return Policy.HandleResult<TResult>(r => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Select(int.Parse).ToList().Contains((int)r.StatusCode))
                .Or<TException>()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                    this.policyConfiguration.NumberOfRequestRetries,
                    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.policyConfiguration.TimeInSecondsBetweenRetries),
                    onRetry: (outcome, retryCount, context) =>
                        {
                            Log.Error($"[{context.PolicyKey}] Retry {retryCount} due to {outcome.Result ?? outcome.Exception.Message}.");
                            if (outcome.Exception != null) throw outcome.Exception; // [*] if desired - see note after code sample
                        })     
                 .WithPolicyKey(nameof(PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync));                      

        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(policyType), policyType, null);
    }
}
```

[*] This line in the code sample above preserves the throwing of the exception within the `onRetry` from the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928173/). However, it would be unusual to rethrow the exception within the `onRetry`, as the policy will not handle the exception rethrown there; throwing within `onRetry` will cause the policy to exit without making further tries.

Comment: I have tried something like this, but when I try to use, I receive this message:

Cannot implicitly convert 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Nest.ISearchResponse<Model.Product>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpRespondeMessage>'

Comment: var PolicyForResultAndException = this.policyFactory.CreatePolicyForResultAndException<HttpResponseMessage, ElasticsearchClientException>(PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync);

Comment: var searchResponse = await PolicyForResultAndException.ExecuteAsync(
                    action: () =>
                        this.client.SearchAsync<Product>(s => s
                        .From((request.PageNumber - 1) * request.PageSize)
                        .Size(request.PageSize)
                        .Index(GetIndexName(request.TenantId))
                        .Query(q => tq), CancellationToken.None),
                    contextData: new Polly.Context("SearchProductSearchAsync"))
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: @GuilhermeFidelis The msg in your 9:23 comment is logical if `Nest.ISearchResponse<Model.Prod‌​uct>` does not implement/extend `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMes‌​sage` (which seems confirmed by the source code at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/ ). With a `Policy<TResult>` handling `TResult` results, you can only execute delegates returning a result convertible to `TResult`. This other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880294/ looks as if it already points correctly to where you can find the `HttpStatusCode` on the response types which ElasticSearch-net makes available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my problem was that I was trying to create a single policy for handling exception and result, while in fact I should create one for each and then merge them with a policyWrap

1st policy (for result):

```
        public Policy<T> CreatePolicyForResult<T>(
        PolicyType policyType)
        where T : HttpResponseMessage
    {
        switch (policyType)
        {
            case PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync:

                var httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying = new List<string>(this.policyConfiguration.HttpStatusCodesToRetrying.Split(','));

                return Policy.HandleResult<T>(r => httpStatusCodesWorthRetrying.Select(int.Parse).ToList().Contains((int)r.StatusCode))
                    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                        this.policyConfiguration.NumberOfRequestRetries,
                        retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.policyConfiguration.TimeInSecondsBetweenRetries))
                    .WithPolicyKey(nameof(PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync));                       

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(policyType), policyType, null);
        }
    }
```

2nd policy (for exception):

```
 public Policy CreatePolicyForException<T>(
            PolicyType policyType)
            where T : Exception
        {
            switch (policyType)
            {
                case PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync:

                    return Policy.Handle<T>()                        
                        .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                            this.policyConfiguration.NumberOfRequestRetries,
                            retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(this.policyConfiguration.TimeInSecondsBetweenRetries),
                            onRetry: (exception, retryCount, context) =>
                            {
                                Log.Error($"[{context.PolicyKey}] Retry {retryCount}  due to {exception.Message}.");
                                throw exception;
                            })                        
                        .WithPolicyKey(nameof(PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync));

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(policyType), policyType, null);
            }
        }
```

Usage:

```
var policyWaintAndRetryForExeption = this.policyFactory.CreatePolicyForException<ElasticsearchClientException>(PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync);

var policyWaintAndRetryForResult = this.policyFactory.CreatePolicyForResult<HttpResponseMessage>(PolicyType.WaitAndRetryAsync);

PolicyWrap<HttpResponseMessage> policyWrap = policyWaintAndRetryForExeption.WrapAsync(policyWaintAndRetryForResult);
```

Comment: It is possible to combine Exception-handling and Result-handling into the same Polly policy.  It is not (in general) necessary to create two separate policies to handle exceptions and results.  (I do not have NEST installed on this machine to check this specific example.)

Comment: The following unit tests in Polly, for example, demonstrate that you can handle both exceptions and results in the same policy: https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/64b21c82d79c2b441be566d06f2dfb5bcfddd338/src/Polly.SharedSpecs/Retry/RetryTResultMixedResultExceptionSpecs.cs#L31-L80

Comment: I've posted an answer now demonstrating how the two separate policies for exceptions and results could be combined.  Hope this is useful.