# Using type constraints from inherited interface gives implicit reference conversion error

Tags: c#, constraints, type-constraints

I have this type constraint

```
where TLookup : ILookupable<ILookup>
```

And I'm passing this interface for the type

```
public interface IEmployeeProxy : ILookupableCode
```

Where you have

```
public interface ILookupableCode : ILookupable<ILookupCode>
```

And

```
public interface ILookupable<T> where T : ILookup
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> LookupByNameAsync(string name, int take = 5, int skip = 0);

    Task<T> LookupByIdAsync(long id);
}
```

And

```
public interface ILookupCode : ILookup
```

But I'm getting the `There is no implicit reference conversion` error and I don't know why, because for me `IEmployeeProxy` is

`IEmployeeProxy` => `ILookupableCode` => `ILookupable<ILookupCode>` => `ILookupable<ILookup>`

What I'm doing wrong here? Why I'm getting this error? For me looks like I should work.

If you want to know why I'm doing this, is because I want to have `ILookupable` with some methods that return `ILookup`, but also have `ILookupableCode` with the same methods of `ILookupable` that will return `ILookupCode` and a few more things too.

Comment: Just because two types, `T1` and `T2` exhibit a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, that *doesn't* imply that `G<T1>` and `G<T2>` will exhibit the *same* relationship. An `ILookupable<ILookupCode>` is *not* related to an `ILookupable<ILookup>`. It's possible it could be but that depends on whether the interfaces are amenable to co-/contra- variance.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever could explain better how `ILookupable<ILookupCode>` is not related to an `ILookupable<ILookup>` ? In what cases this would happen?

Comment: By default it's true. A `List<Bird>` is not a `List<Animal>`, because then someone can stick a `Giraffe` in there.

Comment: @Vencovsky [Covariance and Contravariance in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Comment: Depending on *how* `ILookupable` uses it's `T` parameter there may be something possible here but we can't see how it's using `T`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I updated `ILookupable`

Comment: @Vencovsky it seems that you can try to change signature to `ILookupable<out T> `

Comment: @Vencovsky given I<T>, the fact that A : B doesn't mean that I<A> is assignable to I<B>. You need the generic parameter T in I<T> to be covariant for this to work. That means I<T> has to be defined as I<out T>.

Comment: @GuruStron Are you guys sure? Because doing this `public interface ILookupable<out T> where T : ILookup` gives me this error `Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'ILookupable<T>.LookupByIdAsync(long)'. 'T' is covariant.`

Comment: @Vencovsky well I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to model with ur intfcs, but I'm pretty sure what I wrote about I<A> not being assignable to I<B> holds. Try `List<object> l = new List<string>()` vs `IEnumerable<object> ie = new List<string>().Select(x => x)`. 1st will not compile and 2nd will, cuz List<T> and IE<out T>. The link which Guru Stron posted should point you in the right direction

Comment: @VladiPavelka Now I understand why this doesn't work. Your example of `List` and `IEnumerable` works because `IEnumerable<object>` have a this signature `public interface IEnumerable<out T>` (using out)  but when I'm using `Task<T>`, it's signature don't have out, and that is why it doesn't work. Now I need to find a implementation of `Task<out T>`

Comment: @VladiPavelka This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant) ask what I'm asking now

Comment: @Vencovsky may be [this](https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask) will be useful for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Task<T> not co-variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant)

Answer (score 0):

So the way to fix this would be change the signature of `ILookupable` to `ILookupable<out T>` but this comes with another problem what to do that, my methods need to return an interface type. So this makes impossible to have a method with return type `Task<T>` .

The only walkaround this is using [this third party implementation of `ITask`](https://github.com/jam40jeff/ITask).