# Why Does it Not Compile?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
static List<string> lst = new List<string>();

public static Task<IEnumerable<String>> GetStrings() {
    IEnumerable<String> x = lst;
    
    // This line below compiles just fine.
    // return Task.Run(() => x);
    
    // This line gives a compiler error:
    // Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to
    // 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>'
    return Task.Run(() => lst);
}
```

Why does this line compile just fine: `return Task.Run(() => x);`
while `return Task.Run(() => lst);` gives the compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.List>'
> to
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'

I would think that since `List<string>` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, I should not have to explicitly set `x`. I mean, the compiler knows `lst` is an `IEnumerable<string>`.

I think I must be missing something fundamental here.

Comment: You could fix it with `Task.Run(() => (IEnumerable<String>)lst);`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_AsEnumerable__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__

Comment: The error is about the `Task<T>` types, not Listand IEnumerable. Just because the type parameters have an inheritance relation doesn't mean the generic types have such a relation too

Comment: `Task<TResult>` is not [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: `Task<T>` doesn't state that `T` as `out T` but `IEnumerable` does

Comment: `Task<T>` is invariant (as any other class), only interfaces and delegates support generic variance

Comment: "_But the type of lst and the type of x in the example are both identical_" No they are not. `lst` is `List<string>` whereas `x` is `IEnumerable<string>` at compile time. Runtime type is irrelevant here.

Comment: Another fix would be to await the `Task.Run` and make the method `async`, that way you are returning a compatible object.

Comment: You could fix it with `Task.Run<IEnumerable<String>>(() => lst);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because C# *first* tries to determine the type of your expression `Task.Run(() => lst)` and *then* checks whether it is a suitable return type for your method.

1. `lst` is a `List<string>`.
2. Thus, `() => lst` is a lambda with a return value of `List<string>`.
3. Thus, `Task.Run<TResult>(Func<TResult>)` called with `() => lst` infers `List<string>` as its type parameter `TResult`.
4. Thus, `Task.Run(() => lst)` is of type `Task<List<string>>`.

You then try to use a value of type `Task<List<string>>` as the return value of a method returning a `Task<IEnumerable<string>>`. `Task<TResult>` is not covariant, hence, you get a compile-time error.

(As an aside: Having a covariant `ITask<out TResult>` interface would fix this, but [the .NET development team decided against it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997048/87698).)

Yes, the compiler *could* check how you are *using* the expression created in step 4 and try different interfaces of `lst` to make it fit, but that's a feature that C# (currently) does not have (and which, in my purely personal opinion, is probably not worth implementing and maintaining due to its low cost-benefit ratio).

---

To solve this, you can either provide a different type in step 2, by explicitly casting the return type:

```
return Task.Run(() => (IEnumerable<string>)lst);
```

or by explicitly declaring the type of the lambda expression:

```
return Task.Run(new Func<IEnumerable<string>>(() => lst));
```

or you could override the automatic inference in step 3 with an explicit type argument:

```
return Task.Run<IEnumerable<string>>(() => lst);
```

Comment: C# does seem to be gradually creeping in the direction of analysis of use with it's target-typed expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using different data types here (`List<T>` vs. `IEnumerable<T>`). You can fix the issue with using type casting like:

`Task.Run(() => (IEnumerable<string>)lst);`