# C# method invocation not able to cast classes implementing interface to said interface

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

So I have an app that sends websocket requests to a server and records the responses for later viewing. I would like the user to be able to check off the responses they want to record. I have methods to get all the different response types and each response type implements IWebSocketResponseData. Then I have a method that returns all of the response types based on the CheckBoxData list passed in, it gets all the responses that are checked off from the server and should return a List<IWebSocketResponseData>.

```cs
public async Task<List<IWebSocketResponseData>> GetData(List<CheckBoxData> dataToGet)
        {
            var toReturn = new List<IWebSocketResponseData>();
            foreach (var data in dataToGet)
            {
                var method = GetType()
                    .GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .SingleOrDefault(m => m.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments.Contains(data.ResponseType));
                IWebSocketResponseData response = await (Task<IWebSocketResponseData>)method.Invoke(this, null);
                toReturn.Add(response);
            }
            return toReturn;
        }

        public async Task<ModuleInfoResponse> GetModuleInfo()
        {
            await SendAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                type = "fetch",
                item = "modinfo"
            }));
            return await ReceiveAsync<ModuleInfoResponse>();
        }

        public async Task<NetworkSettingsResponse> GetNetworkSettings()
        {
            await SendAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                type = "fetch",
                item = "network"
            }));
            return await ReceiveAsync<NetworkSettingsResponse>();
        }
```

The two methods below GetData are examples of the methods that would be Invoked from the GetData method. Keep in mind ModuleInfoResponse and NetworkSettingsResponse both implement IWebSocketDataResponse which is just a label basically i.e.

```cs
public interface IWebSocketDataResponse { }
```

This gives me an InvalidCastException trying to cast from any of the concrete response classes i.e. ModuleInfoResponse, NetworkSettingsResponse... Why?

Edit: I realize there is no null check on method cause I know I am gonna get some heat for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Task` is not covariant. In C# [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) can only be applied to generic interfaces (and delegates), so you can do next:

```
public interface IWebSocketDataResponse { }
public class ModuleInfoResponse : IWebSocketDataResponse { }
interface IFoo<out T> // or just interface IFoo<out T> {} for testing purposes 
{ 
    T GetSomething();
    // The following statement generates a compiler error.
    // void SetSomething(T sampleArg);
}

IFoo<ModuleInfoResponse> iX = ...;
IFoo<IWebSocketDataResponse> IXX = iX;
```

But can't:

```
Task<IWebSocketDataResponse> x = Task.FromResult<ModuleInfoResponse>(null);
```

Also please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997048/2501279).

**UPD**

One of the options would be to continue using refection, something like this:

```
var task = (Task)method.Invoke(this, null);
await task;
var response = (IWebSocketResponseData)task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying but how do I get around casting from the Task<> then?

Comment: It might be interesting to mention the difference when using the `await` operator  to consume the task. i.e. `async Task<IWebSocketDataResponse>() => await Task.FromResult<ModuleInfoResponse>(null);`. The difference is intuitive and and ameliorates the invariance of `Task<T>` in many practical scenarios.

Comment: @bturner1273 was glad to help! Also would recommend to cache reflection somehow cause it can be quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Both GetModuleInfo and GetNetworkSettings should be changed to return the interface:

```
public async Task<ModuleInfoResponse> GetModuleInfo()
```

change to :

```
async Task<IWebSocketResponseData> GetModuleInfo()
```

Comment: yeah issue is then I can't reflect to find the proper method :'(

Comment: Very true this only address your invalid cast problem. An option for using reflection would be to assign a custom attribute to GetModuleInfo and GetNetworkSettings and check the attribute value. Your CheckBoxData seems to be related by "modinfo" vs. "network" so perhaps those are candidate values for an attribute.