# Covariance issue when returning Task<T> from a method

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET 6, I have an interface and a type:

```
internal interface IProvider
{
}

public class TProvider : IProvider
{
}
```

I want to use a covariant T in another interface like this:

```
internal interface IFactory<out T>
{
    Task<T> Create();
}
```

But on the line Task<T> Create(), I am getting an error:

> The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on
> 'IFactory.Create()'. 'T' is covariant

If I change the method call to a synchronous version -- T Create() -- it compiles.

Is there a way to keep T as covariant and return Task<T> as part of an asynchronous method signature?

Comment: Natively this isn't possible, it would be good to know more about your use case on what you need this for. There may be alternatives.
There's also a discussion here regarding this state https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2981

Comment: The short answer is "no" (at least currently)

Comment: Related: [Why isn't Task<T> covariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant#:~:text=The%20justification%20is%20that%20the,single%20place%20in%20their%20code).

Answer (score -1):

Change this:

```
internal interface IFactory<out T>
{
    Task<T> Create();
}
```

To :

```
internal interface IFactory<T>
{
    Task<T> Create();
}
```

Comment: The question explicitly says "to keep T as covariant", which is precisely what this *doesn't do*

Comment: @MarcGravell, it won't work as covariant