# Get List of Open Generic Types in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Trying to resolve dynamically a specific implementation based on name (unless there is a better way)

Having a client:

```
public interface IClient { }

public interface IClient<TModel> : IClient where TModel : ListingBase // ListingBase is abstract class
{
    public Task<TModel> MapToObject(Stream file);
}

// base class with common funcationality
public abstract class ClientBase<TModel> : IClient<TModel> where TModel : ListingBase
{
    protected ClientBase(IHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
    }

    public IHttpClient HttpClient { get; }
    
    public abstract Task<TModel> MapToObject(Stream file);
    ... // other stuff
}
```

Implementations:

```
public class Client1 : ClientBase<Model1> // Model1 inherits from ListingBase
    {
{

    public override Task<Model1> MapToObject(Stream file) // Model1 inherits from ListingBase
    {
        // do mapping from Json / Stream to object


        return Task.FromResult(new Model1());
    }
}

// Another client

public class Client2 : ClientBase<Model2> // Model2 inherits from ListingBase
    {
{

    public override Task<Model2> MapToObject(Stream file) // Model2 inherits from ListingBase
    {
        // do mapping from Json / Stream to object


        return Task.FromResult(new Model2());
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in some service I inject ClientFactory where I need to get the right client based on "Name" specified in configs:

```
public interface IClientFactory
{
    IClient<ListingBase> GetClient(string clientName);
}

public class ClientFactory : IClientFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ClientFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
    }

    public IClient<ListingBase> GetClient(string clientName)
    {
        
        var clients = _serviceProvider.GetServices(typeof(IClient)); // this works - I get a list of 2 
        // match by name

        var client = clients.FirstOrDefault(); // TODO - but for now get first
        
        return (IClient<ListingBase>) client; // failing here - invalid cast 
    }

}
```

Error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Client1' to type
> 'Abstract.IClient`1..

In some service want to get a specific client based on a string:

```
public class DefaultProcessor 
{
    private readonly IListingRepository _repository;

    public DefaultProcessor(
        IClientFactory clientFactory, 
        ...
        Client = clientFactory.GetClient("name-from-config");
    }
    

    public async Task Write(Stream file, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var model = await Client.MapToObject(file);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the class definition for `SaborClient` look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can/should Task<TResult> be wrapped in a C# 5.0 awaitable which is covariant in TResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204755/can-should-tasktresult-be-wrapped-in-a-c-sharp-5-0-awaitable-which-is-covarian)

Comment: Updated Name to Client1 (from SaborClient) for clarity. Implementation is Client1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `SaborClient` (that I suppose implement `IClient<?>`) to `IClient<ListingBase>` you need `IClient<T>` to be covariant in `T`, but for that you need `Task<T>` to be covariant in `T` too. Which is not the case because  `Task<>` is a class and variance declaration is only available on interfaces.

You can bypass this limitation with a well constructed interface, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26392948/361177).

Here an implementation example (you need to import [MorseCode.ITask NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MorseCode.ITask/)):

```
public abstract class ListingBase
{
}

public class Model1 : ListingBase
{
}

public interface IClient
{
}

// Note the *out* here
public interface IClient<out TModel> : IClient where TModel : ListingBase
{
    public ITask<TModel> MapToObject(Stream file);
}

public class Client1 : IClient<Model1>
{
    public async ITask<Model1> MapToObject(Stream file)
    {
        return new Model1();
    }
}

public class ClientFactory
{
    public IClient<ListingBase> GetClient()
    {
        var client = GetClientInternal();
        return (IClient<ListingBase>) client;
    }

    private static IClient GetClientInternal() => new Client1();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new ClientFactory();
        var client = factory.GetClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Client:" + client);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, SaborClient aka Client1 inherits ClientBase which impelments IClient<Model> where Model : ListingBase