# Interface<out T> with method returning Task<T> error

Tags: c#, design-patterns

```
public interface IRepo<out T>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> DbFetch();
}
```

I want the method to be a task because DbFetch() will be slow.

> error: Invalid variance: the type parameter 'T' must be invariantly
> valid on 'IRepo.DbFetch()'. 'T' is covariant.

I understand the reasoning for the error but how to get around it so I could await on that method.
Note: cannot remove `out T` because of design requirement elsewhere.

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: 'Task<T> : Task' is the issue. it is not 'out T'

Comment: This is not possible since you're saying that `T` can only be specified in output-positions, whereas in order to provide it to a `Task<T>` it also has to be able to be specified in an input-position.

Comment: I cannot use IAsyncEnumerable<T> as the wait is not on each item but the entire DbFetch() is one REST call.

Comment: Well, you *can* use it -- just the first await will take a while, and the ones afterwards will be synchronous. It also gets around your issue, as `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` is covariant

Comment: If covariance doesn't work, fallback is using the base type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204755/can-should-tasktresult-be-wrapped-in-a-c-sharp-5-0-awaitable-which-is-covarian